How to find x if its in the denominator and on the other side of equal sign.
$$\frac{a}{b+xc} = x $$
So I have $x$ in the denominator on the left side and also $x$ on the right.
$a$, $b$, and $c$ are known and I need to find out for $x$. How should I go about it?
Edit: Thanks for the answers, but the quadratic formula doesn't quite work for me.
I'm trying to insert this into excel. I want to change $a$, according to which $b$ and $c$ will change, and using that I want to find $x$.
I want to write a formula that will find $x$.
Edit 2: I managed to complete it. For the quadratic I was only thinking about the factors, I forgot that this existed: $$x = \frac{-b +- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
Thanks for the help.

Cross multiply and make it a quadratic.

What have you tried so far?

What does your edit mean? How does the quadratic formula not work for you? And do you mean that $b,c$ are functions of $a$?

Welcome to MSE. I think it is important to clarify at the outset whether you require $x$ to be strictly positive (from your edit I think $x>0$ is implied but I do not know the context of your question, so could be wrong). Otherwise, there will be two solutions (not always real) which makes writing an Excel command a bit tricky...

so to clarify, $a$ is an input. $c$ isn't derived from $a$, it has a separate input, but it's closer to a constant as it doesn't change if I change $a$, I would need to change a different input, which woul change $c$.
$b$ is derived from $a$ interacting with another input.

Still, with changing $a,b,c$, why do you think the quadratic formula doesn't work? Though there could be up to two different $x$s, and there are annoying cases for example when $a=0$ or $c=0$.
